# JavaFx form load

Tags: javafx

I want to group some radiobuttons in a togglegroup. The group is created in the controllerclass:

```
final ToggleGroup rbtGroup = new ToggleGroup();
```

Now i create a function which adds those buttons to the group. But how do i fire the function on the so called form-load?

I was writing Visual Basic for my company in the past few months, and there is an event called load on the form. Therefore, i can handle each event (load, change etc.) by simply writing my code in the prevailing event.

How do i achieve that on Java FX?

Excuse me for this question, but i find that the Java FX documentation is very confusing.

Comment: I didn't understand which function should be fired when. Can you explain further what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Your controller class has to implement the `javafx.fxml.Initializable` interface, and override (implement) the only method `initialize()`. This `initialize()` method (there is no `function` in Java terminology) is a "form load function" of the loading FXML file. So you can define and initiate controls and variables in this method like:

```
...
@FXML
private ToggleGroup rbtGroup;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    rbtGroup = new ToggleGroup();

    ToggleButton tb1 = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton 1");
    tb1.setToggleGroup(rbtGroup);

    ToggleButton tb2 = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton 2");
    tb2.setToggleGroup(rbtGroup);
}
...
```

Note the `@FXML` annotation. Put it if the rbtGroup is defined in the loading FXML file.
Or call your "adding buttons to the group" method (again not function) in that `initialize()` method.

Comment: This is a good solution, I wonder why isn't it accepted by OP. I works well on my side. Thanks.